Env variables configured in pod are not visible in Jetty
I have a web application running with Jetty. It is deployed as a pod and uses the jetty:jdk21 base image. In the pod I configure environment variables which are pulled from a secret.
I can see these variables if I go into the pod and run a printenv command. However, when the Java code in my servlet tries to access the same env variables it returns NULL. I use System.getenv.
On the other hand, if I list the existing env variables in Java (looping over the getenv() hashmap) I can see all other env variables but not the ones I set in the pod. It's like the env variables I set using the manifest file has a different "status".
Any idea as to what is going on would be very much appreciated!

Short answer, use docker run -d -u jetty jetty. The Security section of the Readme explains,

By default, this image starts as user root and uses Jetty's setuid module to drop privileges to user jetty after initialization. The JETTY_BASE directory at /var/lib/jetty is owned by jetty:jetty (uid 999, gid 999).
If you would like the image to start immediately as user jetty instead of starting as root, you can start the container with -u jetty:
$ docker run -d -u jetty jetty


Longer answer, setting environment variables for ROOT won't work. You need to ensure they're set for the user jetty. Just running the container as that user should ensure your environment variables are set as expected.
